# IsTextSearchEnabled not working properly on ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to implement the `AutoComplete` feature on `ComboBox` without using `WpfToolkit`. If I'm not wrong, the `ComboBox` should support the `AutoComplete` for a simple string item so for example:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBoxItem>Apple</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Banana</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Pear</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Orange</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

**Current object implementation**

actually my `ComboBox` bound a custom object called `CheckedListItem`, this object have the following structure:

```
public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isChecked;
    private T item;

    public CheckedListItem() { }

    public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set
        {
            item = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
        }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
}
```

this class show as `ComboBoxItem` a `CheckBox` near the `Text` of the `Item`, similar to:

```
[] Item1
[] Item2
...
```

where `[]` is the `Checkbox`.

**ComboBox structure**

The `ComboBox` look like this:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemSource={Binding Countries}/>
```

where `Countries` is a `List` of `CheckedListItem<Country>`, the object country is implemented in this way:

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

the problem on this code is that when I type some text in the `ComboBox` this doesn't do anything, but should display on the items that contains the string typed.

**What I tried so far**

I tried to fix this by implementing a `PreviewTextInput` event, actually I managed in this way:

```
MyComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        CountryMenuComboBox.ItemsSource = Countries.Where(c => c.Item.Name.Contains(e.Text)).ToList();
```

but this doesn't working correctly, cause if I type "England", the `ItemSource` display even all `Items`.

Any idea to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the `TextSearch.TextPath` property to "Item.Name":

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"
          TextSearch.TextPath="Item.Name">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Item.IsChecked}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```